# Matlab: Overlaying only the contour plot lines on an imagesc

Tags: image, matlab, contour

With two matrices of equal size, one representing certain values as a contour plot, and the other a gray and white plot representing the statistical significance of such values (binary values of 0 or 1) as an imagesc plot, I would like to combine them so that I only have the (black) contour lines on top of my white and gray imagesc plot.

So I have two 32x87 matrices:
anomaly
testResults

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
figure
imagesc(testResults.')
colormap(gray)
colorbar
caxis([-2 1])
hold on
clabel(contour(anomaly.'))
colormap(gray)
hold off
```

So one problem is that I cannot find a way to set limits on my contour line colors to keep them all black (since I have clabel, I don't need any variation). Another odd problem I am having is that if I don't use the transpose of anomaly (anomaly.'), it will not show up on this plot. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried playing around with transparency, but it had been really difficult to see much, though I won't rule it out.

Comment: http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/plot_over_image_background
Edit: This is what happened when the picture was turning out unexpectedly while transposing. Check it out. It goes into a lot of detail and provides good examples of how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all the contour lines black by specifying a linespec in the contour command to force all your lines to one kind. That is, try changing your contour command to `clabel(contour(anomaly.', 'k'))`.

Like this:

```
[x y] = meshgrid((1:87)/87);
testResults = sin(x).*sin(y);
anomaly = testResults;

figure
imagesc(testResults.')
colormap(gray)
colorbar
caxis([-2 1])
hold on
clabel(contour(anomaly.', 'k'))
colormap(gray)
hold off
```

[image: ExampleOutput]